# What is use of module in require list but not in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have 2 questions basically.
 1.

1. What is use of "abc/component/database/XYZSettings" in below code snippet.It is not being used in callback function.
2. What is happening after ready function.  With Base Edit

   ```
       <script type="text/javascript">
   require(
       [
           "dijit/registry",
           "dojo/ready",
           "awl/database/BaseEdit",
           "dojo/_base/connect",
           "awl/admin/Subscriptions",
           "abc/component/database/XYZSettings"
       ],
       function(registry, ready, BaseEdit, connect, Subscriptions){
           ready(function(){
               BaseEdit({
                   objId: "Settings",
                   readUrl:'/ui/settings/',
                   updateUrl:'/ui/settings/' ,
                   defaultsUrl:'/ui/settings',
                   creatable:false,
                   deletable:false

               });
           });
        }
   );
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, some modules have uses involving side effects when they're loaded, which don't require referencing their return value directly.  A few examples of this within Dojo itself include:

- The `dojo/domReady!` plugin, which has no meaningful return value, but doesn't resolve until the DOM is ready, thus delaying anything in the callback from running until that point
- Various `dojo/NodeList-*` modules, which add functionality to all `dojo/NodeList` instances (e.g. returned by `dojo/query` calls)
- `dojo/query`, when included for the purpose of event delegation support (which involves use of `dojo/on` but doesn't require directly calling `dojo/query`)

Regarding question 2, `dojo/ready` will wait until any pending modules are loaded and the DOM is ready before calling the callback that is passed to it.  It is usually discouraged in favor of `dojo/domReady!` and `require` in modern Dojo applications.

As for the questions regarding the specific modules here, it's impossible for anyone to say without knowing what those modules actually are, and I'm assuming they're proprietary code in your project.

Comment: Isn't `dojo/ready` commonly used when using declarative markup? It's also one of the reasons a module might be loaded, but not used in the callback... because it's only used for declarative markup.

Comment: @Ken Franqueiro
are they creating Instance of BaseEdit here?

Comment: Well it's being invoked, but whether it's creating an instance would depend on what `BaseEdit` is, which I can't tell from the limited code here.  If it's a constructor created with `dojo/_base/declare`, then yes, since `declare` ensures constructors behave appropriately whether they're invoked with the `new` keyword or not (but using `new` is still encouraged).  Either way, no reference is being retained to whatever `BaseEdit` returns, so I presume it's something with side effects, which isn't typically appropriate of constructors.